# How to interact with swing components in different classes

Tags: java, swing

I'm just trying to figure some things out in my head about getting information to and from swing components from other classes.

I have a main class that uses a few classes to build a swing gui. How do I go about writing information to these components from another class. As far as I understand I need to use an arraylist to store references to these components but I'm not exactly sure how to do this, can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you try to separate the *model* from the *view*. Don't store data relevant for the application logic in the actual GUI components.

Storing references to the components in an array list, and then access the data via the array list and various `getText` methods just seems like a bad idea to me.

Store the values in an object representing some model, and let the GUI reflect the state of the model.

Comment: The data I would be getting would be getting from the components would be text in a jtextarea, does this change anything?

Comment: Depends on what you would do with the text. But back to your question. What is it that you don't understand? Just call `getText` to get hold of the text of the component. This can be done from any class.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm just having trouble grasping some concepts at the moment. The part that's confusing me is I have a class that creates tabs for a jtabbed pane, each pane has a textarea. I want to be able to get the text in the textarea in each pane but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of accessing another class's methods:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
  private final MyBusinessClass bc = new MyBusnessClass();

  @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.bc.someBusinessMethod();
  }
}
```